# the product of an odd perfect number and some even perfect number is perfect

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

If $a$ were an odd perfect number ,does there exist an even perfect number $b$ such that $ab$ is a perfect number?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: @abiessu I wish to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that the EVEN perfect numbers all have the form

$$2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$$, where $2^n-1$ is a Mersenne-prime.

So, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: How do you know the product of any odd number with an even perfect number can not be a number of the form $(2^n - 1)2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Quite easy. An odd perfect number has at least two odd prime factors (in fact, it must have more, but for my disproof, two prime factors are enough). The product of an odd number and an even number is even. If the product would be perfect, it would have only one odd prime factor.

Comment: but the product,if it were to be perfect,would be an "even" perfect,while your contradiction just contradicts the fact that an "odd" perfect number contains at least 2 odd prime factors.Am I wrong in analyzing your proof?

Comment: The product also has the odd prime factors of the odd perfect number, but it cannot have more than one, if it is an even perfect number.

Answer (score 2):

All even perfect numbers are of the form $b=2^{k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)$ (with $2^k-1$ prime, but not needed here.)

Then in $ab=2^{k-1}\left(\left(2^k-1\right)a\right)$ we have $\left(\left(2^k-1\right)a\right)$ must be of the form $2^k-1$, impossible, since $a>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  In general, the product of two perfect numbers (one odd, the other even) is *not perfect*, since every *nontrivial* multiple of a perfect number is abundant.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The strongest possible contradiction. Not only is it impossible that an odd perfect number gives a perfect number when multiplied by a perfect number, but it is even impossible that _any_ number other than 1 gives a perfect number when multiplied by a perfect number.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Suppose $a,b$ are perfect, and $ b$ is even. If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then
$$\sigma(ab)=\sigma (a)\sigma(b)=(2a)(2b)\ne 2ab$$
So $ab$ is not perfect. Hence, we can assume that $ a $ and $ b$ have a common factor. Since $b$ must be of the form
$$2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$$
where $2^n-1$ is prime, and since $a$ is odd, the common factor must be $2^n-1$. So
$$ab=2^{n-1}(2^n-1)^2c$$
where $c$ is odd. This is clearly not of the correct form for an even perfect number.

Comment: In fact I did not recall that $2^n - 1$ is prime and it led me to confusion.